# How to TextRecognize sparse grid of tabular data?

Tags: cluster-analysis, ocr, distance

I cannot give the actual image (contains private information) but the results of

```
TextRecognize[
 ImageResize[img, Scaled[2]], "Word", "BoundingBox", 
 RecognitionPrior -> "Column"]
```

are the following set of rectangles; this being a small portion of the rectangles. (Note: I do not use `"Line"` as third argument as there is no white space in the returned text so no indication of the column the text falls under.)

```
recs =
  {Rectangle[{18, 1140}, {74, 1162}], 
   Rectangle[{622, 1140}, {713, 1162}], 
   Rectangle[{821, 1140}, {875, 1162}], 
   Rectangle[{134, 1088}, {208, 1110}], 
   Rectangle[{214, 1096}, {230, 1098}], 
   Rectangle[{238, 1088}, {284, 1110}], 
   Rectangle[{292, 1082}, {386, 1110}], 
   Rectangle[{623, 1088}, {703, 1110}], 
   Rectangle[{822, 1088}, {871, 1110}], 
   Rectangle[{1137, 1088}, {1201, 1110}], 
   Rectangle[{18, 1036}, {74, 1058}], 
   Rectangle[{134, 1036}, {204, 1058}], 
   Rectangle[{213, 1044}, {228, 1046}], 
   Rectangle[{237, 1036}, {283, 1058}], 
   Rectangle[{291, 1030}, {385, 1058}], 
   Rectangle[{623, 1036}, {703, 1058}], 
   Rectangle[{1137, 1036}, {1198, 1058}], 
   Rectangle[{17, 984}, {74, 1006}], 
   Rectangle[{133, 984}, {301, 1006}], 
   Rectangle[{311, 990}, {318, 992}], 
   Rectangle[{327, 984}, {421, 1006}], 
   Rectangle[{623, 984}, {658, 1006}], 
   Rectangle[{821, 984}, {875, 1006}], 
   Rectangle[{1138, 984}, {1201, 1006}]};
```

The layout of the `"Words"` in the image can be see with

```
Framed[
 Labeled[Graphics[{LightGray, EdgeForm[Blue], recs}], "Words", Top],
 FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

From this example it can be seen that there are 5 columns; actual grids can contain more or less columns. This example also has one "sentence" column; a column made up of several closely spaced (in the x-axis) words; actual grids can contain more or less "sentence" columns.

I would like to cluster each cell of the grid into sublists.  The "sentence" columns will have all of their rectangles in one sublist. The target is clustering is

```
recsByCell = {{Rectangle[{18, 1140}, {74, 1162}]},
   {Rectangle[{622, 1140}, {713, 1162}]},
   {Rectangle[{821, 1140}, {875, 1162}]},
   {Rectangle[{134, 1088}, {208, 1110}], 
    Rectangle[{214, 1096}, {230, 1098}], 
    Rectangle[{238, 1088}, {284, 1110}], 
    Rectangle[{292, 1082}, {386, 1110}]}, 
   {Rectangle[{623, 1088}, {703, 1110}]},
   {Rectangle[{822, 1088}, {871, 1110}]},
   {Rectangle[{1137, 1088}, {1201, 1110}]},
   {Rectangle[{18, 1036}, {74, 1058}]},
   {Rectangle[{134, 1036}, {204, 1058}], 
    Rectangle[{213, 1044}, {228, 1046}], 
    Rectangle[{237, 1036}, {283, 1058}], 
    Rectangle[{291, 1030}, {385, 1058}]}, 
   {Rectangle[{623, 1036}, {703, 1058}]},
   {Rectangle[{1137, 1036}, {1198, 1058}]},
   {Rectangle[{17, 984}, {74, 1006}]},
   {Rectangle[{133, 984}, {301, 1006}], 
    Rectangle[{311, 990}, {318, 992}], 
    Rectangle[{327, 984}, {421, 1006}]},
   {Rectangle[{623, 984}, {658, 1006}]},
   {Rectangle[{821, 984}, {875, 1006}]},
   {Rectangle[{1138, 984}, {1201, 1006}]}};

Framed[
 Labeled[Graphics[
   MapIndexed[{ColorData[109]@*First@#2, #} &, recsByCell]], 
  "Manual Clusters", Top],
 FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I have tried all `DistanceFunction`s while comparing the upper right-hand corner of the first rectangle to the upper left-hand corner of the right-hand rectangle.

```
Module[{df = #, c},
   c = FindClusters[recs, 
     DistanceFunction -> (df[Last@#1, Flatten[List @@ #2][[{1, 4}]]] &)];
   Labeled[
    Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[109]@*First@#2, #} &, c]],
    df, Top]
   ] & /@ 
 Symbol /@ 
  Select[StringEndsQ["Distance"]]@
   EntityValue[
    EntityList[
     EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityAreas" -> "ClusteringSymbols"}]
    ],
   "Name"]//
 Multicolumn[#, 3,
   Frame -> All,
   FrameStyle -> Gray,
   Alignment -> Center] &
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However, none are coming close to the desired result.

Any ideas on how the target clustering can be achieved in general?  There will be both more and less columns and both more and less sentence type columns.

The goal is to recreate the grid of text in the image as `Grid` of strings with matching empty and filled cells.

Comment: maybe `MorphologicalComponents[Dilation[Image[1 - ImageData[Graphics[recs]]], 2]] // Colorize` as a first step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2:** We can get the desired segmentation using the third argument of [`ImageForestingComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageForestingComponents.html) to specify the horizontal and vertical radii to connect two components:

```
ImageForestingComponents[Binarize @ Graphics @ recs, Automatic, {10, 1}] /. 
   1 -> 0 // Colorize // Show[#, ImageSize -> Large] &
```

[image]

Replace `{10, 1}` with  `{5, 10}` to get

[image]

**Update:** Using the horizontal dilation idea with `RegionIntersection` + `RelationGraph` + `ConnectedComponents`:

```
ClearAll[hDilate]
hDilate[d_: 10] := # /. Rectangle[{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}] :> 
     Rectangle[{xmin - d, ymin}, {xmax + d, ymax}] &;

cc = ConnectedComponents[
   RelationGraph[RegionIntersection[hDilate[] @ #, hDilate[] @ #2] =!=  
    EmptyRegion[2]&, recs]];

Sort[cc] == Sort[recsByCell]
```

> True

A slightly modified version:

```
rel = UnsameQ[##] && RegionIntersection[hDilate[]@recs[[#]], 
         hDilate[]@recs[[#2]]] =!= EmptyRegion[2] &;

rg = RelationGraph[rel, Range[Length@recs]];

cc2 = recs[[#]] & /@ ConnectedComponents[rg];

cc2 == cc
```

> True

```
vstyle = Association[Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[# -> ColorData[109]@*First@#2] &, 
     ConnectedComponents[rg]]];

Graph[rg, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> RegionCentroid[recs[[v]]]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, VertexSize -> Large, 
  EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> Directive[CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.5], vstyle[e[[1]]], 
      AbsoluteThickness[20]]}, VertexStyle -> {v_ :> vstyle[v]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Use [`ComponentMeasurements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) to

1. [`Dilate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html) morphological components *horizontally* using the kernel `ConstantArray[1, {1, 10}]`,
2. Find the bounding rectangles
3. [`Erode`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Erosion.html) each bounding rectangle horizontally using the same kernel

```
boundingboxes = Fold[
   Rectangle @@@ 
      ComponentMeasurements[
          #2[Image[1 - ImageData[Graphics[#]]], ConstantArray[1, {1, 10}]], 
          "BoundingBox"][[All, 2]] &, 
   recs, {Dilation, Erosion}];
```

Find the transformation function to map coordinate bounds of `boundingboxes` to coordinate bounds of `recs`:

```
trF = RescalingTransform @@ (CoordinateBounds[# /. 
        Rectangle[a_, b_] :> {a, b}] & /@ {boundingboxes, recs});
```

Transform bounding rectangles:

```
trnsfrmedbb = boundingboxes /. Rectangle[a_, b_] :> (Rectangle @@ trF[{a, b}]);
```

Show transformed boxes together with `recs`:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[], MapIndexed[{ColorData[109]@*First@#2, #} &, trnsfrmedbb2], 
  EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], recs}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Find the box each element of `recs` belongs to using `RegionIntersection`:

```
clusters = recs[[#]] & /@ 
   SparseArray[Outer[Boole[RegionIntersection[##] =!= EmptyRegion[2]] &, 
      trnsfrmedbb, recs]]["AdjacencyLists"];
```

The result matches OP's manual clusters:

```
clusters == recsByCell
```

> True

Show `clusters` using OP's color coding:

```
Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[109]@*First@#2, #} &, clusters], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. May you give a brief sentence on what each line of code is doing. (+1)

Comment: @Edmund, added some notes.